# Playing ringtone & vibrating phone?

Tags: android

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when); 
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent); 
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; 
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; 
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS; 
notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00; 
notification.ledOnMS = 300; 
notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
```

---

```
Change in manifest :
<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
```

I have added the above code. its running without errors. But no effects are seen. Does it run on android 1.5 ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap this notification setup into a notification manager call.

See some tutorial about [notificationmanager](http://www.anddev.org/show_notification_in_statusbar-t1019.html)

```
mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mManager.notify(APP_ID, notification);
```